# Overcome Wordpress Memory Exceeded Limit, WITHOUT changing server's limit

Tags: php, wordpress

My server's limit is set to 8MB. I want wordpress to work, however it must be incredibly bloated if it needs to use over 8MB just to get to the admin page. I have no plugins, it's a fresh install.

Is there anyway i can strip it down so that it no longer causes this error? I will not change the memory limit to larger than 8mb

Comment: imho, 8mb peak memory is not bloated.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message and the code lines around the error.

Comment: You can free memory by unseting vars (unset($uge_value)) with a lot of data after usage.

Comment: You don't think that 8mb for a blog system is bloated? Just to run the admin panel?

The error is;
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 8388608 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 46080 bytes) in /****/blog/wp-admin/includes/file.php on line 522

Answer (score 3):

I do not think so. Have a look at [this discussion of Wordpress.com](http://wordpress.org/extend/ideas/topic.php?id=2968)

Six plugins (though it probably depends on the plugins) consume over 16MB and a German localized version eats through 24MB of memory in no time.

**EDIT:**

You can install [TCP! Memory Usage](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tpc-memory-usage/) and take a look at how much memory your application is acctually using and try to lower the "define(’WP_MEMORY_LIMIT’, ’64MB’);" in your wp-config.php.

Comment: As the limit is set to 8MB I tried setting the wp_memory_limit var to 8MB before posting this question and still receive the same errors unfortunately. But thanks :) It looks like it's trying to use over 12MB, probably around 14 I'd say.

Comment: Also, I can't install that plugin as I can't access the admin panel :P

Answer (score 0):

I think from discussing it with my colleagues we've decided to program our own blog system, should only take a couple of hours, and most definitely won't use all that memory :)

Thanks for your suggestions, keep them coming, might help me at a later date (or someone else for that matter).